# PHP: MSSQL Query for multiple fields on one page

Tags: php, sql-server

I am new to PHP, and have a web form, that I am using PHP to get data from the database. What I have currently done, as I havent been able to find out another solution to do so (despite my searching - probably dont know the correct terms to look for), is individually executing a SQL Query for each input field on my form.
As below:

```
            <div class="search-line">
                <div class="search-option">
                    <label>Asset Tag:<i title=""></i></label>

                    <?php

                    $asset_tag_sql = "SELECT HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetAssetTag FROM HardwareAsset WHERE HardwareAssetID = '".$_SESSION["HardwareAssetID"]."'";
                    $asset_tag = sqlsrv_query($database_connection, $asset_tag_sql);

                    ?>

                    <input type="text" id="AssetTag" disabled value="<?php while ($asset_tag_option = sqlsrv_fetch_object($asset_tag)){echo $asset_tag_option->HardwareAssetAssetTag;} ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="search-option">
                    <label>Serial Number:<i title=""></i></label>

                    <?php

                    $serial_number_sql = "SELECT HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetSerialNumber FROM HardwareAsset WHERE HardwareAssetID = '".$_SESSION["HardwareAssetID"]."'";
                    $serial_number = sqlsrv_query($database_connection, $serial_number_sql);

                    ?>

                    <input type="text" id="SerialNumber" disabled value="<?php while ($serial_number_option = sqlsrv_fetch_object($serial_number)){echo $serial_number_option->HardwareAssetSerialNumber;} ?>" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Is there anyway to have one PHP piece of code to do one SQL query and then use that to fetch and echo the value for both input fields, as opposed to the two above?

Comment: You can `SELECT` both, separated by comma in a single query.

Comment: Simply select both, as mentioned by fzr... 
`$asset_both_sql = "SELECT HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetAssetTag, ardwareAsset.HardwareAssetSerialNumber FROM HardwareAsset WHERE HardwareAssetID = '".$_SESSION["HardwareAssetID"]."'";`

Comment: @roko - i have tried this but when i load the page, i get no errors, but the second input and any subsequent input values are always blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this?

```
<?php
$asset_sql = "SELECT HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetAssetTag,HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetSerialNumber FROM HardwareAsset WHERE HardwareAssetID = '".$_SESSION["HardwareAssetID"]."'"
$asset_result = sqlsrv_query($database_connection, $asset_sql);
$asset_data = sqlsrv_fetch_object($asset_result);
?>

<div class="search-line">
    <div class="search-option">
        <label>Asset Tag:<i title=""></i></label>
        <input type="text" id="AssetTag" disabled value="<?php echo $asset_data->HardwareAssetAssetTag; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="search-option">
        <label>Serial Number:<i title=""></i></label>
        <input type="text" id="SerialNumber" disabled value="<?php echo $asset_data->HardwareAssetSerialNumber; ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect, thank you very much, thats been bothering me for a long time, with so many unnecessary server side calls.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just select two fields from the initial query like this:

```
$serial_number_sql = "SELECT HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetSerialNumber, 
HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetAssetTag FROM HardwareAsset WHERE 
HardwareAssetID = '".$_SESSION["HardwareAssetID"]."'";
```

Comment: i have tried this but when i load the page, i get no errors, but the second input and any subsequent input values are always blank

Comment: It's possible that the query is returning no results. Have you checked the session variable $_SESSION["HardwareAssetID"] to make sure it contains a valid value?

Comment: it does work when two separate queries, both using the variable. I have echo's the $serial_number_sql and pasted direct into SQL Management Studio and returned the results I was expecting. I assumed it was something to do with the PHP syntax which meant i could only return one value at a time or something